# Will a vSphere client 5.1 task get cancelled/interrupted if I close out of the client?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I have a 700GB server image copying from one datastore to another on the same host, using the vSphere client version 5.1.

I used copy and paste. This created a task, and it's been 5 hours and only 14% of the task has completed.

I am using my laptop to perform this task, and I need my laptop to do something else that would require me to switch networks, forcing me to exit out of the vSphere client.

Question: Would the copy task be cancelled or interrupted if I close out of the client? If so, is there a workaround I can use to keep the task running and letting me exit out of the client?

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing anything where you're moving data to/from the host, then no.. you cannot disconnect and resume. If the task has been backgrounded and is running on the host-only or being managed by vCenter, then you can disconnect.

A quick test of this would be to open another vSphere client session and check the task list.

Comment: I opened a second vSphere Client Session and the task was still running. It's all happening in the same host. Just to confirm, this would mean I am safe to disconnect correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @ewwhite Hey man, unrelated question. How can I co-relate the hard drives in vcenter -> settings -> hardware tab to the actual partitions on disk. Do you think this warrants a separate question. I am not much good with vmware.

Comment: @SohamChakraborty Separate question.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/609330/identify-disks-in-vcenter-to-partitions-in-linux-guest Here you go, good sir.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be interrupted/canceled. Its not the same as doing a upload. I assume you used copy and paste in the vSphere client.

Comment: Yes I did use copy and paste. It's all in the same host too.

Comment: Your good to go.